# EVA not working after update

Tags: 7, views, entities

After a safety update from Drupal 7.56 to Drupal 7.58 I also updated [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) (7.x-3.18 > 7.x-3.20) and [EVA: Entity Views Attachment](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva) (7.x-1.3 > 7.x-1.4), most Views are working fine, just the ones with EVA aren't.

What I'm trying to achieve again is listing the talks *(programmpunkt)* on each event day *(kongresstag)*, linked through [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference).

Is there anything I'm missing here? I'd be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction..

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'vortr_ge_in_kongresstagen';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'Vorträge in Kongresstagen';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Vorträge im Plenum';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_text'] = 'mehr';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['submit_button'] = 'Anwenden';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['reset_button_label'] = 'Zurücksetzen';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['exposed_sorts_label'] = 'Sortieren nach';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['sort_asc_label'] = 'Aufsteigend';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['sort_desc_label'] = 'Absteigend';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'table';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['row_class_special'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['columns'] = array(
  'path' => 'path',
  'field_datum_und_zeit' => 'field_datum_und_zeit',
  'title' => 'title',
  'field_subtitle' => 'title',
  'field_speaker' => 'title',
  'field_cerps_' => 'title',
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['default'] = '-1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['info'] = array(
  'path' => array(
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'field_datum_und_zeit' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => 'views-align-right',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'title' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => 'views-align-left',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'field_subtitle' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'field_speaker' => array(
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'field_cerps_' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => 'views-align-right',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
);
/* Relationship: Entity Reference: Referenced Entity */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_punkt_kongresstag_target_id']['id'] = 'field_punkt_kongresstag_target_id';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_punkt_kongresstag_target_id']['table'] = 'field_data_field_punkt_kongresstag';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_punkt_kongresstag_target_id']['field'] = 'field_punkt_kongresstag_target_id';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_punkt_kongresstag_target_id']['required'] = TRUE;
/* Feld: Inhalt: Pfad */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['path']['id'] = 'path';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['path']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['path']['field'] = 'path';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['path']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['path']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['path']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Feld: Inhalt: Datum und Zeit */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_datum_und_zeit']['id'] = 'field_datum_und_zeit';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_datum_und_zeit']['table'] = 'field_data_field_datum_und_zeit';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_datum_und_zeit']['field'] = 'field_datum_und_zeit';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_datum_und_zeit']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_datum_und_zeit']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_datum_und_zeit']['settings'] = array(
  'format_type' => 'uhrzeit',
  'custom_date_format' => '',
  'fromto' => 'value',
  'multiple_number' => '',
  'multiple_from' => '',
  'multiple_to' => '',
  'show_remaining_days' => 0,
  'field_formatter_class' => '',
);
/* Feld: Inhalt: Titel */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Feld: Inhalt: Subtitle */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_subtitle']['id'] = 'field_subtitle';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_subtitle']['table'] = 'field_data_field_subtitle';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_subtitle']['field'] = 'field_subtitle';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_subtitle']['label'] = 'Untertitel';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_subtitle']['alter']['make_link'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_subtitle']['alter']['path'] = '[path]';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_subtitle']['element_type'] = 'span';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_subtitle']['settings'] = array(
  'field_formatter_class' => '',
);
/* Feld: Inhalt: Speaker */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_speaker']['id'] = 'field_speaker';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_speaker']['table'] = 'field_data_field_speaker';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_speaker']['field'] = 'field_speaker';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_speaker']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_speaker']['element_type'] = 'span';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_speaker']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_speaker']['settings'] = array(
  'field_formatter_class' => 'table-speakers',
);
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_speaker']['delta_offset'] = '0';
/* Feld: Inhalt: CERPs */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_cerps_']['id'] = 'field_cerps_';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_cerps_']['table'] = 'field_data_field_cerps_';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_cerps_']['field'] = 'field_cerps_';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_cerps_']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_cerps_']['element_type'] = 'div';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_cerps_']['element_class'] = 'cerps';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_cerps_']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_cerps_']['settings'] = array(
  'field_formatter_class' => 'cerps',
);
/* Sort criterion: Inhalt: Datum und Zeit -  start date (field_datum_und_zeit) */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_datum_und_zeit_value']['id'] = 'field_datum_und_zeit_value';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_datum_und_zeit_value']['table'] = 'field_data_field_datum_und_zeit';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_datum_und_zeit_value']['field'] = 'field_datum_und_zeit_value';
/* Sort criterion: Inhalt: Titel */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['title']['field'] = 'title';
/* Contextual filter: Inhalt: Nid */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['id'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['field'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['relationship'] = 'field_punkt_kongresstag_target_id';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['exception']['title'] = 'Alle';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['default_argument_type'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['specify_validation'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['validate']['type'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['validate_options']['types'] = array(
  'kongresstag' => 'kongresstag',
);
/* Contextual filter: Inhalt: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth) */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['id'] = 'term_node_tid_depth';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['field'] = 'term_node_tid_depth';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['exception']['title'] = 'Alle';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['default_argument_type'] = 'fixed';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['default_argument_options']['argument'] = '6';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['depth'] = '0';
/* Filter criterion: Inhalt: Veröffentlicht */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Inhalt: Typ */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'programmpunkt' => 'programmpunkt',
);
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['group'] = 1;

/* Display: EVA Field */
$handler = $view->new_display('entity_view', 'EVA Field', 'entity_view_1');
$handler->display->display_options['entity_type'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['bundles'] = array(
  0 => 'kongresstag',
);
$handler->display->display_options['show_title'] = 1;
$translatables['vortr_ge_in_kongresstagen'] = array(
  t('Master'),
  t('Vorträge im Plenum'),
  t('mehr'),
  t('Anwenden'),
  t('Zurücksetzen'),
  t('Sortieren nach'),
  t('Aufsteigend'),
  t('Absteigend'),
  t('Inhalt entity referenced from field_punkt_kongresstag'),
  t('Untertitel'),
  t('Alle'),
  t('EVA Field'),
);
```

Comment: What does "EVA" stand for?

Comment: @NoSssweat Thanks for pointing that out, I just edited my question and added links to the project page on drupal.org